# ORACLE PL/SQL Result will be on a table format

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

Hi is there a way that I can convert the output of my script into a table ?

note:enhance pivot is manually created funtion

```
    set serveroutput off
    var rc refcursor

    begin  
    :rc := enhance pivot(  
    '(select TYPE , ATTR_NAME,  ATTR_VALUE from TEMP_5 
    where TYPE = ''**SAMPLE 1'' )' ,  
    'max( ATTR_VALUE)',  
    'ATTR_NAME'  
    );  
    end; 

    print:rc
```

Output ( note: i've just cut the columns b'coz it's too long)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIxau.jpg)

Comment: Not sure what you are asking but if you can covert your RC to string variable and use proper  create statement then you can create using dynamic sql

Comment: i can't understand your problem, provide more Information.

Comment: `print :rc` looks like a SQL\*Plus command, possibly printing the contents of a previously populated `refcursor` variable. But it could be other things. Please post enough context for us to understand your question if you hope to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: Yes ! Your right @APC, 

And the Output of the RC is a number of fields under 1 row ( may vary on filter) which displayed above.. my question is how can I put that into a table..

Comment: hi @hotfix , I updated my post. thanks

Comment: @BhanuYadav, please refer to my updated post including the script

Comment: @Gabriel, Your question is still not clear as print rc prints the output of cursor as u requested. What I understand from the question if you want to store the output of cursor in a table means you will create a dynamic cursor and create a table according to the cursor and store in that table into the database. Correct if I am wrong and if you can send input and output it will be helpful.

Comment: @Bhanu Yadav, Yes your right just to add, the column length of this script is depend on TYPE meaning it can be 10..11..12..13..and so on...